# Cannot able create variable in jenkins DSL shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

i got below error when i create a new variable (MY_VARIABLE) in jenkins shell script. In jenkins dsl shell script i just want to create a variable and assign some default value and print it.

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 12) No such property: MY_VARIABLE for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:112)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_runScripts_closure1.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:59)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$runScripts$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScript(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:85)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
at com.sheehan.jobdsl.DslScriptExecutor.execute(DslScriptExecutor.groovy:27)
at com.sheehan.jobdsl.ScriptExecutor$execute.call(Unknown Source)
```

The jenkins code is

```
job('ci') {
    description 'Build and test the app.'

    scm {
        github 'sheehan/job-dsl-playground'
    }
    steps {
        gradle 'test'
    }
    shell("""#!/bin/bash 
        MY_VARIABLE=5
        echo $MY_VARIABLE
    """)
    publishers {
        archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to escape dollar symbol:

```
job('ci') {
    description 'Build and test the app.'

    scm {
        github 'sheehan/job-dsl-playground'
    }
    steps {
        gradle 'test'
    }
    shell("""#!/bin/bash 
        MY_VARIABLE=5
        echo \$MY_VARIABLE
    """)
    publishers {
        archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
 }
```